# How to use expect on existing ssh sessions in perl scripts with bash scripts already piped to them

Tags: bash, perl, ssh, while-loop, expect

I have a perl script that pulls hostnames from a database and ssh's to them en masse with bash scripts piped to those ssh sessions for monitoring purposes.

These hosts overwhelmingly have root keys and in addition to monitoring I'm trying to justify further use of root keys to better facilitate this monitoring method.

Here is an example (the context is a while loop in the perl script):

```
system("cat /usr/local/bin/filesystem_scan.sh | ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root\@$name '/bin/bash; uname -a &> /dev/null' ");
```

There is another bash script that runs the perl one and gets result codes from the script that was piped and edits them into a report.

```
#!/bin/bash

perl /usr/local/bin/readonly-fs-scan.pl | grep -v " 0$\| 127$" | column -t > report.txt
```

The problem is that the script takes forever to run (over 500 hosts) because of approximately 50 hosts that don't have root keys. As a stop-gap to getting approval for keys on those servers I'm trying to find a way to implement expect into this process so that `return` is sent any time a password is requested (otherwise the script stalls for over a minute waiting for input for each of those 50 hosts, which causes a script that should take about 5 minutes to run to take about an hour). I've been able to do this in a simple bash script that ssh's to one server like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "set timeout 5
spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$name
expect \"*password:\"
send \"\r\""
```

However I'm struggling to grasp how I can insert this into the perl script.

This is a work assignment so I'm limited in large-scope changes I can make - (changing code language, installing extra utilities, etc.)

Comment: Perl has its own Expect module [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect).

Comment: Expect cannot interact with existing ssh sessions.

Comment: Should be able to run those logins in parallel, what should help _a lot_, since it's all network bound -- any reason that you can't?  (Or do you already?)